# Identity of Running maximum

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

let $X_t$ denotes a arithmetic Brownian motion process.
I am wondering if the following identity is true ?
$$
\mathrm{P}\left[\sup_{0 \le s \le t} \mathrm{e}^{X_t} < x\right] = 
\mathrm{P}\left[\sup_{0 \le s \le t} X_t < \ln{x}\right],
$$
How may we show this result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that we work on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Define the set $A$ in $\Omega$ by $$A:=\{\omega \in \Omega | \sup_{0\leq s \leq t} e^{X_t(\omega)} < x\}.$$ Since the exponential is invertible we easily see that this is equivalent to the definition

$$ A:= \{\omega \in \Omega | \sup_{0\leq s \leq t} X_t(\omega) < \ln x\} .$$
So the probabilities of these sets must be equal.

Comment: I suspected this was true for all stochastic processes,  I will revise my question to reflect that. Thank you